# Were any California presidios conquered?

Tags: california

During the Spanish and Mexican eras in California, there were five presidios in the region: San Diego, Santa Barbara, Monterey, San Francisco, and Sonoma.  Were any of these ever conquered, taken over, or destroyed?  (During the Spanish and Mexican eras, that is.)

Comment: Don't know if it counts, but: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidio_of_Santa_Barbara#Mexican-American_War

Answer (score 16):

Yes:

- The presidio of Monterey was destroyed by the Argentine-sponsored privateer Hippolyte Bouchard in 1818.
- The presidio of San Francisco capitulated to the pro-Spanish forces of Joaquin Solís in 1829.
- The presidio and town of Monterey were occupied by Jones of the USA in 1842.

Answer (score 3):

Rebels of the Bear Flag Revolt took the Sonoma Presidio in June 1846. They made it their stronghold. The revolt didn't advance much further, however Sonoma was never retaken (though efforts had been made) before the US military came in July peacefully acquiring Sonoma from the "Bears" having declared California for the United States.

- [history.com](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/californias-bear-flag-revolt-begins)
- [NPS.gov](https://www.nps.gov/goga/learn/historyculture/bear-flag-revolt.htm)
- [wend.ca](https://wend.ca/?p=54823)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Republic#Capture_of_Sonoma)